# How to sort an array of dictionaries according to time in swift

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, date

I am trying sort an array of dictionaries according to a key which has date. So, the sorting actually has to be done on the basis of dates. But I don't know why sortedArrayUsingComparator is not sorting the array and I am getting the older array back itself. The values are all coming correctly in the objects (obj1, obj2) though.

Here is the filter array:

```
(
        {
        age = 26;
        "already_reported" = no;
        "already_sync" = no;
        "complete_name" = "Ghazalahhhhhhhhhhhhh Khan";
        distance = "7.92353";
        "first_name" = Ghazalahhhhhhhhhhhhh;
        id = 288;
        "last_chat_details" =         (
                        {
                "from_xmpp_id" = ghazalah41e21475158541;
                id = 9614;
                message = H;
                "message_est_timing" = "2016-11-02 08:30:09";
                timestamp = 1478075409813132;
                "to_xmpp_id" = annungdg1475217973;
                "xmpp_message_id" = "F67A8495-E700-485B-A0B3-49C854E4FA45";
            }
        );
        "last_name" = Khan;
        "last_played_music" =         (
                        {
                album = "Haan Kargi (Jatt.fm)";
                artist = "Ammy Virk (Mr-Jatt.com)";
                bpm = 0;
                "created_at" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
                duration = "3.55";
                genre = "Single Tracks (Mr-Jatt.com)";
                id = 69251;
                "is_recently_played" = 1;
                "persistent_id" = 7705218523513871878;
                title = "Haan Kargi (Mr-Jatt.com)";
                "updated_at" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
                "user_id" = 288;
            }
        );
        "matched_profile_image" =         (
                        {
                "est_date_time" = "2016-10-04 04:08:34";
                id = 479;
                "image_order" = 3;
                "is_profile_image" = no;
                "main_image_id" = 2225;
                "main_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/934820161004080721.jpg";
                "thumb_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/t_934820161004080721.jpg";
                "user_id" = 288;
            },
                        {
                "est_date_time" = "2016-10-04 04:08:34";
                id = 480;
                "image_order" = 2;
                "is_profile_image" = no;
                "main_image_id" = 2226;
                "main_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/685220161004080800.jpg";
                "thumb_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/t_685220161004080800.jpg";
                "user_id" = 288;
            },
                        {
                "est_date_time" = "2016-10-28 06:08:37";
                id = 552;
                "image_order" = 1;
                "is_profile_image" = yes;
                "main_image_id" = 2313;
                "main_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/825720161028100832.jpg";
                "thumb_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/t_825720161028100832.jpg";
                "user_id" = 288;
            }
        );
        "short_description" = Church;
        username = ghazalah41e21475158541;
    },
        {
        age = 26;
        "already_reported" = no;
        "already_sync" = no;
        "complete_name" = "Michael Berrin";
        distance = "7.92490";
        "first_name" = Michael;
        id = 310;
        "last_chat_details" =         (
                        {
                "from_xmpp_id" = michaelgbmh1477565051;
                id = 9143;
                message = Hi;
                "message_est_timing" = "2016-11-01 07:43:46";
                timestamp = 1477986226750744;
                "to_xmpp_id" = annungdg1475217973;
                "xmpp_message_id" = "CD8FD64D-1370-41AD-8731-BC2A4C16EB6D";
            }
        );
        "last_name" = Berrin;
        "last_played_music" =         (
                        {
                album = "T-Series";
                artist = "";
                bpm = 0;
                "created_at" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
                duration = "5.04";
                genre = "";
                id = 72284;
                "is_recently_played" = 1;
                "persistent_id" = 4446247237416765338;
                title = "Dheere Dheere Se Meri Zindagi Video Song (OFFICIAL) Hrithik Roshan, Sonam Kapoor | Yo Yo Honey Singh - YouTube";
                "updated_at" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
                "user_id" = 310;
            }
        );
        "matched_profile_image" =         (
                        {
                "est_date_time" = "2016-10-27 07:04:10";
                id = 543;
                "image_order" = 4;
                "is_profile_image" = no;
                "main_image_id" = 2303;
                "main_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/186120161027110402.jpg";
                "thumb_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/t_186120161027110402.jpg";
                "user_id" = 310;
            },
                        {
                "est_date_time" = "2016-10-27 07:12:52";
                id = 544;
                "image_order" = 3;
                "is_profile_image" = no;
                "main_image_id" = 2304;
                "main_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/132120161027111225.jpg";
                "thumb_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/t_132120161027111225.jpg";
                "user_id" = 310;
            },
                        {
                "est_date_time" = "2016-10-27 07:12:52";
                id = 545;
                "image_order" = 1;
                "is_profile_image" = yes;
                "main_image_id" = 2305;
                "main_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/270620161027111236.jpg";
                "thumb_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/t_270620161027111236.jpg";
                "user_id" = 310;
            },
                        {
                "est_date_time" = "2016-10-27 07:12:52";
                id = 546;
                "image_order" = 2;
                "is_profile_image" = no;
                "main_image_id" = 2306;
                "main_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/920120161027111247.jpg";
                "thumb_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/t_920120161027111247.jpg";
                "user_id" = 310;
            }
        );
        "short_description" = "";
        username = michaelgbmh1477565051;
    },
        {
        age = 22;
        "already_reported" = no;
        "already_sync" = no;
        "complete_name" = "Lisa Benson";
        distance = "7.92195";
        "first_name" = Lisa;
        id = 287;
        "last_chat_details" =         {
        };
        "last_name" = Benson;
        "last_played_music" =         (
                        {
                album = "";
                artist = "";
                bpm = 125;
                "created_at" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
                duration = "3.1";
                genre = "";
                id = 76890;
                "is_recently_played" = 1;
                "persistent_id" = 577117298;
                title = "Avicii -";
                "updated_at" = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
                "user_id" = 287;
            }
        );
        "matched_profile_image" =         (
                        {
                "est_date_time" = "2016-09-29 08:54:10";
                id = 459;
                "image_order" = 2;
                "is_profile_image" = no;
                "main_image_id" = 2200;
                "main_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/858820160929125409.jpg";
                "thumb_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/t_858820160929125409.jpg";
                "user_id" = 287;
            },
                        {
                "est_date_time" = "2016-10-04 06:58:35";
                id = 481;
                "image_order" = 1;
                "is_profile_image" = no;
                "main_image_id" = 2227;
                "main_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/292820161004105734.jpg";
                "thumb_image_path" = "/files/profile_images/t_292820161004105734.jpg";
                "user_id" = 287;
            }
        );
        "short_description" = "";
        username = lisavmds1475153650;
    }
)
```

Here is my code, please help:

```
let tempArr: NSArray! = self.filteredArray.sortedArrayUsingComparator({
            (obj1:AnyObject!, obj2:AnyObject!) -> NSComparisonResult in
            let dateStr1 = (obj1["last_chat_details"] as! NSArray).firstObject!["message_est_timing"] as! String
            let date1: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr1 as String)!
            let dateStr2 = (obj2["last_chat_details"] as! NSArray).firstObject!["message_est_timing"] as! NSString
            let date2: NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateStr2 as String)!

            return date2.compare(date1)

        }
    )

    print("the temp msgs are\(tempArr)")
enter code here
```

Comment: can you show the output ?

Comment: Why `NSArray`?? Swift can sort a native array in one line.

Comment: Note that `date2.compare(date1)` will do a descending sort

Comment: I Don't even know where to start on this. Force casting out the wazoo, unneeded type annotations, unwarranted use of foundation types ... Sorry boys, I've gotta nope out of this one. No way. Nope. nu uh.

Comment: @Ghazalah could you post your the containment of `filteredArray`? I would like to see your data structure.

Comment: Guys how should I send the array...they are too long to send in the comments...@vadian I tried sorting in one line too but with same results

Comment: it must be the problem of data structure, the sort compare the `message_est_timing` of the *firstObject* in the array `last_chat_details`. This timing can be already ordered.

Comment: @dirtydanee have added the filterArr in my ques

Comment: `as! String` and `as! NSString` for the same kind of objects? Are `date2` and `date1` `nil`? I mean, is the `(NS)DateFormatter` correctly set?

Comment: @Larme String NSString does not matter...and yes the dateFormatter is working fine and I am getting dates in both

Comment: @Ghazalah String/NSString, is more about a logic issue, homogeneity in your code. Also, that should avoid the `as String` in your `dateFromString()`.

Comment: Guys, can I expect some amount of solution for my problem from the ones who downvoted the question?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
let array = [
    ["message_est_timing" : Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 100)] ,
    ["message_est_timing" : Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 300)] ,
    ["message_est_timing" : Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 400)]
]
let newArr = array.sorted { (dict1, dict2) -> Bool in
    let date1 = dict1["message_est_timing"]!
    let date2 = dict2["message_est_timing"]!
    return date1.compare(date2).rawValue == 1 ? true : false
}
```

newArr will be sorted correctly by date.

Comment: There's also a `last_chat_details` in there